# Control characters in environmental variables mess up the output of `export`

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I have some control variables in some environmental variables, but the output of the simple `export` command is messy due to these characters. See the screenshot:

[image: messy export command output]

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is this an issue? If you print the output to a file, it will be completely acceptable to the shell. If you want to see what's there, use something like `cat -v` or `hexdump` on the file.

Answer (score 1):

I can cofirm that this happens. I am not sure if there is a proper way to solve this, but I hacked a partial solution:

```
printenv -0 |
    while IFS= read -r -d '' s; do
        printf "declare -x %s=%q\n" "${s%%=*}" "${s#*=}"
    done
```

This should produce an output that is *almost* equivalent to the output of `export -p`, except that it will properly escape all special characters in the values of the variables. One issue is that `printenv` does not print the exact same list of variables as `export -p` (e.g. in my system, `export -p` includes the `$OLDPWD` but not `$_`). I only use `printenv` because it supports the `-0` option.

*Example*: If you do `export myvar=$'\E[01;31mtest'` and then run my script, the output will include the following:

```
declare -x myvar=$'\E[01;31mtest'
```

whereas if you type `export -p` will get a lot of lines printed in red (assuming that your terminal supports color).